# HOW TO get URL Content from UserInput

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the url content from user input

```
package edu.psgv.sweng861;

import java.net.*; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*; 
/**
 * A complete Java class that demonstrates how to read content (text) from a
 * URL using the Java URL and URLConnection classes. There is no user input in
 * this program, just a hard-wired url to fetch a conforming Http live streaming
 * playlist.  
 */
 public class JavaUrlConnectionReader {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
         System.out.println("Enter URL:");
         String userUrl = myObj.nextLine();  // Read user input
         System.out.println("User URL is: " + userUrl);  // Output user input 
     }

     private static String getUrlContents(String theUrl) {
         String content = "";
         try {
             URL url = new URL(theUrl);
             URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
             String line;
             while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                 content += line + "\n";
             }
             bufferedReader.close();
         } catch(Exception e) {
             System.out.println("The url was invalid, please try again");
         }
         return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? Please specefiy, what the problem is?

Comment: it won't catch the exception.

Comment: Okay but does an exception occur at all? It's very hard to help, without having more details?

Comment: the user input have to be URL , If the user input was something else like integer it won't catch it . when you run, it just shows enter url in thew console

Comment: You should validate the user input, when you get it from the user... Not when you try to make the URL request

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that

Comment: Yes i have added answer with a method you can use

Comment: If you found it useful, please accept the answer, so the question can be answered

Answer (score 1):

You should validate, the url, when the user gives it in, not when trying to establish the connection. Your URL method is only responsible for one thing, not validating the data.

Instead you should make a method, that can validate the data, as the user gives it in. Here is an example

```
public static boolean isValidUrl(String url, String regexPattern){
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
    Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(url);
    return matcher.matches();
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://youtube.com";
        String urlRegex =  "\\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
        System.out.println("Url is valid: " + isValidUrl(url, urlRegex)); //URL is valid, and it will print true
    }
```

below i added a working example of some boolean logic, you could use to validate your scanner input

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String url;
    do{
        System.out.println("Please enter your url");
        url = scan.nextLine();
    }while(!isValidUrl(url));
    System.out.println("The Url was successfull"); //executs only if when the conditions is not met
}
```